# Inno Setup - Prevent desktop shortcut from opening a subfolder instead of running executable with the same name

Tags: matlab, inno-setup, shortcut-file

I use Inno Setup to create installation files and recently found an issue and I can't see a workaround.  My app is not launched directly, it is launched from inside another program, `matlab`.  So my `Files` and `Icons` look like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "include\*"; Excludes: "License"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: matlab; \
    Parameters: "-r ""run '{app}\nCAL\nCAL_RUN.p'"""; IconFilename:"{app}\nCAL.ico";
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: matlab; \
    Parameters: "-r ""run '{app}\nCAL\nCAL_RUN.p'"""; IconFilename:"{app}\nCAL.ico"; \
    Flags: useapppaths
```

This works fine UNLESS there happens to be a folder called `matlab` in the Desktop at the time of running Inno Setup compile.

The correct desktop shortcut has these properties:

Target

```
C:\MATLAB\R2018b\bin\matlab.exe -r "run 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ricardo\Global DoE Toolkit\nCAL\nCAL_RUN.p'"
```

Start in

```
C:\MATLAB\R2018b\bin
```

However, if by chance there's a (empty or otherwise) folder called `matlab` on the desktop then the installer creates a shortcut with these properties:

Target

```
"C:\Users\jse\OneDrive - Ricardo Plc\Desktop\Matlab" -r "run 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ricardo\Global DoE Toolkit\nCAL\nCAL_RUN.p'"
```

Start in

```
"C:\Users\jse\OneDrive - Ricardo Plc\Desktop"
```

And the shortcut just opens the `matlab` folder in Explorer.

I can't specify the `C:\MATLAB\R2018b\bin\matlab.exe` part explicitly because the user could have any version of `matlab` in any folder.  I assume the installer gets the path from the registry.

Any help as to why it falls down and what the fix might be would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matlab.exe` as the shortcut target, to distinguish it from the `matlab` folder.

```
Filename: matlab.exe;
```

Comment: Ah, so simple!  Thanks very much.